# Are there many almost complex structures on a (complex) manifold?

Tags: complex-geometry, almost-complex

I guess one can have many almost complex structures on a manifold, can someone give me an example? How about when the manifold is complex? is the almost complex structure induced by the complex structure the only one?

Comment: No manifold has one almost complex structure. If $J$ is an almost comlpex structure, then so is $-J$.

Comment: If a manifold has one almost complex structure, then the space of all almost complex structures on it (we can even restrict to those that are homotopic to our original one) is an infinite-dimensional manifold in a certain sense (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202139). One can calculate the rational homotopy type of this space of almost complex structures to see that it is usually non-trivial; for example, the space of almost complex structures on $S^6$ has the rational homotopy type of $S^7$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $J :TM \to TM$ is an almost complex structure on $M$, and let $\varphi : TM \to TM$ be a bundle automorphism. Set $J_{\varphi} = \varphi\circ J\circ \varphi^{-1}$, then

\begin{align*}
J_{\varphi}\circ J_{\varphi} &= \varphi\circ J\circ \varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi\circ J\circ \varphi^{-1}\\
&= \varphi\circ J\circ J\circ \varphi^{-1}\\
&= \varphi\circ (-\operatorname{id}_{TM})\circ\varphi^{-1}\\
&= -\varphi\circ\operatorname{id}_{TM}\circ\varphi^{-1}\\
&= -\operatorname{id}_{TM}
\end{align*}

where we have used the fact that $\varphi$ is linear on fibres in the penultimate equality.

Therefore, if $M$ admits an almost complex structure $J$, every bundle automorphism $\varphi$ gives rise to another almost complex structure $J_{\varphi}$, but not every almost complex structure on $M$ arises in this way.

Comment: By definition, an integrable almost-complex gives rise to a complex structure. But if $J_1,J_2$ are different integrable complex structures, does it follow that they induce different complex structures?

Comment: Might I ask a trivial question, is the space of   almost complex structures connected, i.e. two almost complex structure can be deformed by a path in the space of almost complex structures?

Comment: @DLIN: No, the space of almost complex structures can have infinitely many connected components, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4621458/39599) for example.

Answer (score 4):

One important example is the 1-dimensional one: For Riemann surfaces, all almost complex structures are integrable (see e.g. Theorem 11.1.6 of [these notes](http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/fanhj/courses/symp-11.pdf)). On the other hand, surfaces generally admit many different complex structures, and these are parametrized by [Teichmüller space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichmuller_space).