# All almost complex structures on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, almost-complex

I read the statement of the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, which says that "any integrable almost complex structure is induced by a complex structure".

To make sense of the statement, I was wondering how many almost complex structures there are in the first place, i.e. if there is any way to determine *all* almost complex structures on a given manifold. The sphere admits a complex structure as $\mathbb P^1$, but I know that the complex structure on $\mathbb P^1$ is rigid, i.e. cannot be deformed.

As a next non-trivial example I considered $\mathcal O(k)$, which in real terms would be a twisted rank 2 bundle over the sphere.

My question is now, how can I determine all almost complex structures on $\mathcal O(k)$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{O}(k)$?

Comment: Also, is there any reason to think that the space of almost complex structures on a given manifold (up to diffeomorphism) would be finite-dimensional?  It seems very unlikely to me that it would be.  Assuming it's not, what sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @JimBelk $\mathcal O(k)$ is the complex line bundle (real rank 2 bundle) of Chern class $k$ over $\mathbb P^1\cong S^2$ (see the notation [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle#The_tautological_bundle_on_projective_space)). I loosely expect the space to be finite-dimensional, because the space of complex structures on $\mathcal O(k)$, $k$ neg., is finite-dimensional (this one has to calculate). Even if it isn't finite-dimensional, though, one should be able to construct at least a one-parameter family of almost complex structures for the theorem to be of any practical value.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52960/which-almost-complex-manifolds-admit-a-complex-structure) on Math Overflow?  One of the answers has a link to [these](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/57245?uid=3739832) [two](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/10/3/303.full.pdf) papers.  There is also [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81373/non-integrable-almost-complex-structures-for-homogeneous-spaces).  If none of these answer your question, I'd recommend posting on Math Overflow.

Comment: Michael Albanese's answer on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485863/are-there-many-almost-complex-structures-on-a-complex-manifold?rq=1) question shows that whenever you have an almost complex structure $J: TM \to TM$ and a bundle automorphism $\phi : TM \to TM$, you get another almost complex structure $J_{\phi} : TM \to TM$. On the other hand, if $J$ is an almost complex structure, then $-J$ is also an almost complex structure, which is not related by a bundle automorphism.